# authenticate request token passed in url

Tags: spring, spring-security

As per our requirements:
According to token based url, we should pass the token in the url as:

`url(http://localhost:8080/{contextpath}/{token}/{resource path})`.

The token is passed after the `context path`, and before the `resource path`, as in:
    `{contextpath}/{token}/{resource path}))`
How can the server delegate the request to respective resource class when the `token` is present *between* the `context path` and `resource path`?

example url: `http://localhost:8080/sampleweb/DES@3e$@#3423ASD/userdetails.do`

In the above url:
`context path` is "sampleweb",
`token` is "DES@3e$@#3423ASD", and
`resource` is "userdetails.do".

If user enters the above url, the server delegates to the particular user class,
such that the `context path` is `sampleweb`.

Comment: Edits: typos, grammar, code formatting, edits for clarity, remove unnecessary comments.  OP: please review edits.  I understand English is not your first language.  I tried to clarify your question as best I could, but some bits were unclear, and I *may* not have got them exactly correct (sorry).  Click `edit` to fix any mistakes, or add info.  Also, in the end, I'm not sure what *exactly* you are having trouble with.  Please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Where does the server *currently* take the user?  How does this differ from where you *want* the server to take the user?

Comment: fix typo `httpL:`... to `http:'...  While it is usually frowned upon for non-OP users to fix code typos, as [the typo] *could be the actual source of the OP's issue*, I do not believe this to be the case here.  1) he does not indicate any error messages. 2) it's clear that the code was manually typed, rather than copy-pasted, 3) I was already making extensive edits so the Q could be understood and useful to the community, and for the OP to get an answer.  4) Q seems to be about the *process*.

Comment: "If user enters the above url, the server delegates to the particular user class" do you mean the corresponding controller? What are your attempts so far?